# Strange behavior of control position in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

It's a strange behaviour about the WPF Control positioning. I had a below controls and aligned well during design time. However runtime gave the misaligned positioning in the corner of button

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.LookAndWork"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Tables" Height="388" Width="314" ResizeMode="NoResize" >
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Margin="12,12,12,41"></TextBox>
        <Button Content="OK" Height="23" Margin="205,314,12,12" Name="button3" Width="75" IsCancel="True"  IsEnabled="False" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

DesignTime Snap

[image: Design Time]

Runtime Snap

[image: Runtime]

Suppose If i removed the ResizeMode="NoResize" from the Window. I can able to see the correct positioning at runtime. What is the problem with ResizeMode="NoResize" ?

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: OT: **Do not** use fix margins to layout the controls in a view! There are a bunch of layout controls which were created for this job. I know you're using the designer. I strongly recommend to do the layout directly in the XAML. If you want to reuse your view or the requirements are changing you will have a lot of work to implement them.

Comment: This might be related to the TextBox above the button because it will resize in steps (a line at the time). Try enabling the resize of the form and then slowly resizing the form. See if you see the jumping of the textbox.

Comment: please use microsoft express blend 4 otherwise set properties VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignment

Comment: I'd suggest to you to move your button into separate grid row.

Comment: @Pranav1688 Why use Blend?

Comment: i think you don't know why express blend 4 used for. @Thorsten Dittmar

Comment: @Pranav1688 I do, but there's no need to use cannons on sparrows in that case. It's pretty sufficient (and far more efficient for developers) to learn how to write XAML by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding the margin in control level, why don't you add the minimum margin in grid level?

Example:

```
<Grid Margin="12,12,12,12">
```

This way you will get a 12 pixel margin border.
On the button, don't do hardcoded left margin. Instead, you can use `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` to do the job.

On a side note, I less prefer to add controls in grid without specifying the Grid.RowDefinitions, Grid.ColumnDefinitions, Grid.Row and Grid.Column. It is a poweful tool for Grid.

Answer (score 2):

For better looking, don't use Margin or Size. Use Grid definition to split your application.

With the following xaml, your application will always have a good looking :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="23" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="OK" Name="button3" IsCancel="True"  IsEnabled="False" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Width and Height can be define in a Dictionary. In this case, in RowDefinition and ColumnDefinition properties, use Auto instead of values.

**Edit :**
Use a Dictionnary like

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="75"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="23"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

then

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="OK" Name="button3" IsCancel="True"  IsEnabled="False" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: While I understand why you set the width of the column hosting the button, why do you explicitly set the height? The button can pretty well also have its default height.

Comment: i have editing. The better way is to define Width and Height of common control (button) in a Dictionnary, then set Height and Width of Definitions at "Auto"

Comment: This again fixes the height of the button to 23 pixels, only in another location. By the way: as you did it, all buttons in the entire application are 75x23 pixels, right?

Comment: Right, all buttons have the same size. But you can, for exceptions, set manually the size in the Xaml, or define a sub-type of button in the Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the same issue in VisualStudio 2012 designer: http://screencast.com/t/TGVgUyfR
Both design-time and runtime are look the same. So there should be a bug in a prior version of the designer.
Nevertheless I'd suggest you to move your button into separate grid row or use another layout controls to organise your views.

Comment: I tried the layout, but no hope even it was aligned incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

To extend Xaruth's answer, I'd not fix the height for the button row, but instead have it use the default height. The same goes for the width, which I'd have the button define.

Also note that I give the button a margin. The added bonus of not fixing the grid column/row sizes it that now the row height also takes the margin into account:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="OK" Name="button3" IsCancel="True"  IsEnabled="False" Width="75" Margin="0,8,0,0" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```